# htaccess preventing index.html from loading automatically

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got the following htaccess file in my website's root folder:

```
# Deny access to everything by default
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all

# Allow access to html files
<Files *.html>
    allow from all
</Files>
```

I do this to prevent access to everything but html files.  However, it also seems to be preventing index.html from loading automatically (eg. navigating to http://www.website.com fails).  But if I specifically request index.html (eg. http://www.website.com/index.html), I can access it.

How can I deny access to everything but html files and still have index.html load automatically?

Comment: Note: I've already tried adding a DirectoryIndex index.html statement and specific Files rule to allow index.html, and neither f those helped. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add a FilesMatch rule to get this working:

```
# Deny access to everything by default
Order Deny,Allow
deny from all

# Enable the redirect to index.html
<FilesMatch ^$>
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>

# Allow access to html files
<Files *.html>
    allow from all
</Files>
```

This essentially allows anything matching an empty request path.  I believe the problem here was that the allow/deny rules were being applied to the incoming request before the automatic index redirect was applied.  So essentially the request for http://www.website.com/ would come in, not match any of the whitelisted file types, and be denied by the blanket deny from all statement.  Apparently this was short-circuiting the request at that point - before it could be automatically redirected to a request for index.html, which would have been allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the DirectoryIndex directive in your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and it doesn't seem to fix the problem...  the site is hosted on godaddy shared, so I'm wondering if maybe they have some strange configuration higher up that is causing this.